# try to get all products by category id but get only enable products in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

How can i get all the products(including disable) programmatically? in Magento2. 
try to get all products by category id but got only enable status products.

My code is :

```
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load($categoryid);
$collection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Comment: @ManthanDave thanks but Category is already enable.

Answer (score 0):

Used the following query to fetch all the enabled and disabled products of a particular category.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();


$collection = "SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity AS e 
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product AS at_category_id ON (at_category_id.product_id=e.entity_id)
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar  AS product ON (product.entity_id=e.entity_id)
WHERE at_category_id.category_id IN (57,60)
GROUP BY e.entity_id
ORDER BY e.entity_id ASC";

$result = $connection->fetchAll($collection);
```

Above code will directly to a query from the database and give you the appropriate result.

NOTE: Please change category Ids as per your store category value.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}


$collection->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore(0));//0 is default store
```

Answer (score 0):

please Try below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$productFac = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$categoryId = 'yourcategoryid';
$category = $categoryFactory->load($categoryId);
$collection = $productFac->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better and more actual way to get products by category - via `ProductRepository` and built-in Filters (from Magento 2.2)

```
public function __construct(
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteriaBuilder
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->criteriaBuilder = $criteriaBuilder;
}

/**
 * @return ProductInterface[]
 */
public function getProducts(): array
{
    $categoryIdsToExport = $this->config->getCategoriesToExport();

    return $this->productRepository->getList(
        $this->criteriaBuilder
            //It's Custom Filter from di.xml
            ->addFilter('category_id', $categoryIdsToExport, 'in') 
            //Here you cat filter products in standart Magento way
            ->addFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->addFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
            ->create()
    )->getItems();
}
```

Unfortunately There are few info in stackexchange about "Search Criteria Unify Processing" - better and currently proper way to filter,sort models.

[Here Magento doc about Search Criteria Unify Processing](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html#m2devgde-searchcriteria-unify-processing)

Also you can register your own CustomFilter to filter products.
See example in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml` :

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\ProductFilterProcessor" type="Magento\Eav\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="customFilters" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- You can specify your attribute and map a class to apply filter -->
            <item name="category_id" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\ProductCategoryFilter</item>
            <item name="store" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\ProductStoreFilter</item>
            <item name="store_id" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\ProductStoreFilter</item>
            <item name="website_id" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\ProductWebsiteFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    public $productCollectionFactory;
  
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    )
    {    
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    
    public function getProductByCategories($ids)
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => ids]);
        return $collection;
    }
```